# О междометиях и запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Интересует междометие "о". Нужно ли его отделять запятой в таких, например, восклицаниях, как "О(,) да!" или там, где есть обращение: "Дошло до меня, о(,) великий халиф..."?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенных примерах слово О является усилительной частицей и не выделяется запятой: О да! Дошло до меня, о великий халиф.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Одни и те же слова могут являться частицей или междометием. Междометия выражают  различные чувства (удивление, восхищение, испуг, понимание), а частицы  имеют усилительное или побудительное значение.
2. Междометия произносятся с интонацией обособления, то  есть составляют отдельную фразу с интонационным ударением,  которая выделяется  паузой.   На частицы никогда не падает ударение, и они произносятся без паузы.
3. Примеры парных вариантов:
    О, я как брат обняться с бурей был бы рад! О, это была райская жизнь! (Это выражение волнения, восхищения).
     О верь, я жизнь тебе отдам!  (Это значения усиления: частица  О + глагол).
4. Перед обращением может находиться как частица, так и междометие:

О любимые сердцем обманы!   Ты не забудешь дружбы нашей, о Пущин, ветреный мудрец!  О поле, поле! Кто тебя усеял мёртвыми костями?

О, Вера, посмотри, как красиво! О, тоска моя, кручина! Пожалей ты сироту!
 О, память сердца! Ты сильней рассудка памяти печальной.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ПРАКТИЧЕСКИЕ СОВЕТЫ)

1. Надо обязательно прочитать предложение с обособлением частицы-междометия и без обособления. Иногда сразу становится ясным, какой вариант верный: О любимые сердцем обманы!
2. Если оба варианта возможны, то попробуйте убрать или переставить обращение. Если это возможно, то слово перед обращением является междометием: О, посмотри, как красиво, Вера!
3. Междометие "О" всегда находится в начале предложения, поэтому "О" в середине предложения является частицей:Дошло до меня, о великий халиф.
4. В некоторых случаях решение является авторским: О, память сердца! Ты сильней рассудка памяти печальной. Здесь возможен вариант с частицей "О память сердца!"